# PostgreSQL Trigger to keep track of table changes

Tags: postgresql, tracking, trigger

I am trying to create a trigger (PostgreSQL 9.4) to track changes made to a table. This is my approach:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION taxon_history() RETURNS trigger AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
        INSERT INTO history.taxon(operacao, "data", tecnico, original_oid, taxon)
        VALUES ('DELETE', current_timestamp, current_user, old.oid, old.taxon);
        RETURN old;

    ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        INSERT INTO history.taxon(operacao, "data", tecnico, original_oid, taxon)
        VALUES ('DELETE', current_timestamp, current_user, old.oid, old.taxon);
        RETURN old;

    ELSIF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO history.taxon(operacao, "data", tecnico, original_oid, taxon)
        VALUES ('INSERT', current_timestamp, current_user, new.oid, new.taxon);
        RETURN old;
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER history_taxon
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON taxon
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE taxon_history();
```

However when something changes in the `taxon` table, no record is added to the `taxon_history` table. I also don´t get any error message so I am in the dark on why nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since there is no GIS-centric component to this task, [dba.se] might be a better place to ask this. Either way, you should certainly [Edit] the question to specify the exact release of PostgreSQL in use.

Comment: Thanks Vince, will do that.